# How to implement GraphQL cursor in SQL query with sort by

Tags: sql, postgresql, graphql, database-cursor

I have a database table `reviews` with `id`, `rating` where id is auto-incrementing and rating is an integer between 0 and 100.

I'm attempting to create cursor based pagination in a GraphQL API but am struggling to create the necessary queries for `hasPreviousPage` and `hasNextPage`.

Here is my data:

```
ID: 1, RATING: 50
ID: 2, RATING: 80
ID: 3, RATING: 20
ID: 4, RATING: 40
ID: 5, RATING: 60
```

---

Here's an example of a GQL query:

```
reviews(first: 3)
```

Which returns

```
ID: 1, RATING: 50
ID: 2, RATING: 80
ID: 3, RATING: 20
```

With pageInfo

```
hasPreviousPage: false
hasNextPage: true
```

The queries for pageInfo would be

```sql
hasPreviousPage = SELECT COUNT(*) > 0 FROM reviews WHERE id < 0;
hasNextPage     = SELECT COUNT(*) > 0 FROM reviews WHERE id > 3;
```

---

My issue comes when sorting by rating.
Making a query similar to before:

```
reviews(sort: "rating", first: 3)
```

Which returns

```
ID: 3, RATING: 20
ID: 4, RATING: 40
ID: 1, RATING: 50
```

With pageInfo

```
hasPreviousPage: false
hasNextPage: true
```

But how can I create the queries for `hasPreviousPage` and `hasNextPage` like I did before?

```sql
hasPreviousPage = SELECT COUNT(*) > 0 FROM reviews WHERE ???
hasNextPage     = SELECT COUNT(*) > 0 FROM reviews WHERE ???
```

What should the WHERE clause be in this case? Does the query need to be a lot more complex with a sub query? I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't actually need any DB queries for `hasPreviousPage` and `hasNextPage`.
You need to apply the +2 trick to achieve this (given that you want to implement `hasPreviousPage` for both before and after cases).

Let's say you have this query:

```
// `after` should be URL-safe encoded
// `id` must have a monotonic sort order, a ULID is a fine choice for an id
// if ULID is not an option for some reason, chose a different column that has a monotonicity to it, e.g. `created_at`
reviews(first: 3, after: "id:12345;sort_cols:user_id")
```

What you want to do is to query for the first 5 reviews:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM reviews
WHERE id >= ?
ORDER BY ? ASC
LIMIT 5;

-- result: 12345, 12346, 12347, 12348, 12349
-- from the app return (after computing `pageInfo`): 12346, 12347, 12348
```

If the `id` of the first result matches the id in the cursor, i.e. `12345` it means there is a previous page.
If there is a previous page and the number of returned rows is 4 or less, `hasNextPage: false`.
If there is **not** a previous page and the number of returned rows is 4 or more, `hasNextPage: true`.

Before you return the results, make sure to filter out the item matching the cursor id (`12345`) and the one extra item if there is a next page.

Beware that the SQL has to be generated correctly. The query would change depending on the direction of the pagination (`before` vs. `after`). It also becomes more complex if you want to support range requests, i.e. ones where `before` and `after` are supplied at the same time.

Example:

```
reviews(first: 3, before: "id:12345;sort_col:user_id")
```

Here you want to use a descending order.
Also, you need to filter on ids <= the id from your cursor.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM reviews
WHERE id <= ?
ORDER BY ? DESC
LIMIT 5;

-- result: 12345, 12344, 12343, 12342, 12341
-- from the app return (after computing `pageInfo`): 12344, 12343, 12342
```

Comment: This was explained so clearly. Thank you very much Attila, I'll try to implement it like this!

Comment: Am I missing something or does this not actually sort by "rating". It's sorting by id so the result set won't be correct?